# Php multiple search dropdowns

Tags: php, mysql, search, multiplication

I'm having hard time, thinking out how can I make a PHP dropdown search for a real estate website.

So I have made the MYSQL cities and properties but I don't know how to make the categories and when you search like a Mobile Phone to come another dropdown menu and to select the phone model and to display the results in another page.

- the cities list: http://prikachi.com/images.php?images/747/7206747u.jpg
- the property type: http://prikachi.com/images/776/7206776v.jpg

p.s. sorry but I could post it like codes..

Answer (score 0):

Use Ajax with PHP by onchange event.
as:

```
<select id='drpdwn1' onchange='getdata(this.value)'>
   <option value='-1'>Please Select</option>
   <option value='1'>Example1</option>
   <option value='2'>Example2</option>
</select>
<select id='drpdwn2' onchange='getdata(this.value)'>
  <option value='-1'>Please Select</option>
</select>
```

//

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js" ></script>
<script>

function getdata(value){
jQuery("#drpdwn2").html("<option>Some Option</option>");
}
function getdatabyAjax(value){
$.post('URL_here',{param:value},function(data){
    jQuery("#drpdwn2").html(data);
    });
}
</script>
```

//
when user select example1, javascript getdata() will be called and by ajax, value will be redirected to drpdwn2.

Comment: can u give me more directions?